# Center google maps marker when it moves out of current window

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a tracking application where users will be tracking cab assigned to them. I am able to center the cab position on each move but that gives a feel like map is moving instead of cab moving.

I would like to know if there is anyway by which I can center the cab position on map when it is moving out of current window on mobile app. i.e As long as the new cab position is within the map loaded at that moment, I will just animate moment to new marker position, but when the new location of cab is out of current bounds I will need to set the new position of cab as the center of the screen and animate the cab movement (or animating while dragging kind of experience would be great).

Please suggest if there is anyway I can achieve this.!

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just check if the new location is contained within the map visible region:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng current = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    if (!mMap.getProjection()
            .getVisibleRegion()
            .latLngBounds
            .contains(current)) {
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(current));
    }
}
```